# Using Gulp Use-Ref with Express

Tags: node.js, express, gulp

I can't seem to get [use-ref](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-useref) to work with Express due to Express doing the compilation of Jade and not having control over the compilation with my build files using Gulp.

Does anyone know if it is possible to get use-ref to work with Express?, and if so, could you please provide an example.

This would solve so many problems, as all asset managers for Node, seem to be very specific and are not very extensible.